# Having issues running group comparison Shapiro-Wilks test for RMANOVA

Tags: r, anova, rstatix

I'm currently using the "weightloss" dataset from the datarium package to start running an RMANOVA. Here is the dput:

```
dput(head(weightloss))
structure(list(id = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), 
    diet = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), exercises = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    t1 = c(10.43, 11.59, 11.35, 11.12, 9.5, 9.5), t2 = c(13.21, 
    10.66, 11.12, 9.5, 9.73, 12.74), t3 = c(11.59, 13.21, 11.35, 
    11.12, 12.28, 10.43)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So this is the script I have come up with so far:

```
# Create Data Frame for Dataset:

weight <- weightloss
weight

# Pivot Longer Data to Create Factors and Scores：

weight <- weight %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = 'trial', # creates factor (x)
               values_to = 'value', # creates value (y)
               cols = t1:t3) # finds which cols to factor

# Plot Means in Boxplot:

ggplot(weight,
       aes(x=trial,y=value))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(title = "Trial Means") # As can be predicted, inc w/time
```

I get this pretty normal looking boxplot:

[image: Boxplot]

Now its time to find outliers and test for normality.

```
# Identify Outliers (Should be None Given Boxplot):
    
    outlier <- weight %>% 
      group_by(trial) %>% 
      identify_outliers(value)
    outlier_frame <- data.frame(outlier) 
    outlier_frame # none found :)

# Normality (Shapiro-Wilk and QQPlot):

model <- lm(value~trial,
            data = weight) # creates model
shapiro_test(residuals(model)) # measures Shapiro
ggqqplot(residuals(model))+
  labs(title = "QQ Plot of Residuals") # creates QQ
```

This again gives me a pretty normal QQplot:

[image: QQPLOT]

I then wrapped the data by trial:

```
ggqqplot(weight, "value", ggtheme = theme_bw())+
  facet_wrap(~trial)+
labs(title = "QQPlot of Each Trial") #looks normal
```

And it comes out right from what I can tell:

[image: QQPLOT FACETED]

However, when I try to do a Shapiro Wilk test by group, I keep having issues with this code:

```
shapiro_group <- weight %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  shapiro_test(value)
```

It gives me this error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `data`. i `data = map(.data$data, .f, ...)`. x Must group by variables found in `.data`.
>
> - Column `variable` is not found.

I also tried this:

```
shapiro_test(weight, trial$value)
```

And get this error instead:

> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column `trial$value`
> doesn't exist.

If anybody has some insight as to why, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you were getting an error for `shapiro_test` was because the implementation of it has this one line in it.

```
shapiro_test
function (data, ..., vars = NULL) 
{
....
....
 data <- data %>% gather(key = "variable", value = "value") %>% 
        filter(!is.na(value))
....
....
}
```

where it gets the data in long format using `gather`. Since you already have a column named `value` this doesn't work.

If you change the name of `value` column to anything else it works.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)

weight %>%
  rename(value1 = value) %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  shapiro_test(value1)

#  trial variable statistic     p
#  <chr> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
#1 t1    value1       0.869 0.222
#2 t2    value1       0.910 0.440
#3 t3    value1       0.971 0.897
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly it. I ended up just changing the original name in my original pivot_longer command and then changing everything to "score" to keep everything consistent in my script. Appreciate it Ronak!